# How to call socket.io authorization after user login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is there any way how to call socket io authorization after the user logs in? Because i want to authorize every  users who logs in. I've read how to node's article about [socket.io](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth) but this tutorial automatically authorize when someone connected to the server. Do you have any idea on how to do calling socket.io authorize? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
io.configure(function (){
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    callback(null, true); // error first callback style 
  });
});
```

So, `io.set` and after the identification logic fire the callback with the possible error and a boolean allowing or disallowing the connection.

In the **socket.io** [wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki) is [very well explained](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#global-authorization).

**Edit:**

Sorry, I haven't anwered your question.

You can fire the socket.io functionality after your user log in. You can use plain http before log and sockets.io afterward.

Just dont fire `io.connect('...');` from the beginning.